# Why I have to use tnsnames.ora in Oracle SQL Developer to connect some database

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, tnsnames

when I log on some oracle database, I can connect without tnsnames.ora. However, when I try to log on some other database, it reject because of TNS:connection timeout. What is changed? What does TNS file do? Why I have to have this ora file?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

File `tnsnames.ora` just resolves your database alias to full databases address.

Assume you have an entry as this:

```
ORA11 =
 (DESCRIPTION = 
   (ADDRESS_LIST =
     (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.1.0)(PORT = 1521))
   )
 (CONNECT_DATA =
   (SERVICE_NAME = ORA12)
 )
)
```

Then you can start for example SQL*Plus

```
sqlplus SCOTT@ORA11
```

or

```
sqlplus SCOTT@"(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.1.0)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=ORA12)))"
```

It does the same, the first way is just more convenient.